# Teamcity build failing when using SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, teamcity-7.1

I am using TeamCity Enterprise 7.1 and when trying to run a build using SVN as VCS root, I get below errors -
I have completed successful builds earlier also. I just copy the configuration from previous build configuration and rename it with pointing to new branch.

```
jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl$1: Server was not able to build correct patch, most likely due to VCS errors 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.throwError(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:114)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.checkPatch(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:104)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.copyPatchAndCheck(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:65)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.UpdateSourcesPatcherBase.copyPatchToTempFile(UpdateSourcesPatcherBase.java:70)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.UpdateSourcesFromServer.updateSources(UpdateSourcesFromServer.java:62)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.UpdateSourcesBuildStageBase.doSourceUpdate(UpdateSourcesBuildStageBase.java:91)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.UpdateSourcesBuildStageBase.doRecoverableStage(UpdateSourcesBuildStageBase.java:59)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.RecoverableBuildStage.doLastAttempt(RecoverableBuildStage.java:112)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.RecoverableBuildStage.doBuildStage(RecoverableBuildStage.java:70)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:31)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.callRunStage(StagesExecutor.java:78) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.doStages(StagesExecutor.java:37) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor.doStages(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunAction.doStages(BuildRunAction.java:70) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunAction.runBuild(BuildRunAction.java:50) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.doActualBuild(BuildAgentImpl.java:243) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.access$100(BuildAgentImpl.java:48) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl$1.run(BuildAgentImpl.java:216) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.UnsuccessfulPatchException: Failed to build patch for build #BUILD_2 {build id=31289}, VCS root: svn: svn://prtl-dev-src1/branches/Portal-2.4.0 {instance id=8647, parent id=505}, due to error: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E210004: Malformed network data 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.AbstractPatcher$1.fail(AbstractPatcher.java:93) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.LowLevelPatcher.readPatchStream(LowLevelPatcher.java:156) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.LowLevelPatcher.applyPatch(LowLevelPatcher.java:79) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.AbstractPatcher.applyPatch(AbstractPatcher.java:42) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchApplierImpl.applyPatch(PatchApplierImpl.java:18) 
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.checkPatchInFileIsCompleted(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:84)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.checkPatch(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:94)
    ... 18 more
```

Can someone please help me what can be the issue? How to fix this?

Comment: Did you end up finding the solution?

Comment: ping... Trying to fix this at 5pm on a Friday...

Comment: Same issue here on TeamCity Enterprise 9.1.7.